# Enforce keys of array of generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm not sure if the title describes my situation properly so I'd appreciate any edits in case there's a better way to phrase it.

I have a helper function that takes in a Database model and allows for the searching of rows in the Database table that belongs to the model.

It can be simplified as having three parameters, the database model, a search phrase, and the fields (columns) in which to look for the search phrase.

Right now I'm using a generic type called `ModelAttributes` in order to dynamically determine which fields are allowed to be passed to the `fields` property of the search function like so:

```js
type ModelAttributes<SpecificModel> = {
  // First filter only keys that are strings
  [Field in keyof SpecificModel]: SpecificModel[Field] extends string
    ? // Of the string based keys, if they are generic to the Model type ignore them
      Field extends keyof Model
      ? never
      : Field
    : never;
}[keyof SpecificModel];

type SmartSearchParams<SpecificModel extends StandardModel> = {
  search: string;
  model: SpecificModel;
  fields: ModelAttributes<SpecificModel>[];
};
```

The problem is that I want the function to also have another parameter called `associatedModels` of the following type:

```js
type AssociatedQueryTypes<AssociatedModel> = {
    model: AssociatedModel,
    fields: ModelAttributes<AssociatedModel>
}
```

Now you can pass a parameter called `associatedModels` with an array of the `AssciatedQueryTypes` and it should also validate that any fields used there belong to the model that was passed alongside it as well.

The problem arises because I don't know how to properly add the new type to the `SmartSearchParams` type.

I've tried the following:

```js
type SmartSearchParams<SpecificModel extends StandardModel> = {
  search: string;
  model: SpecificModel;
  fields: ModelAttributes<SpecificModel>[];
  associatedModels: AssociatedQueryTypes<any>[]; // The 'any' is a problem
};
```

Now when I try to use the function it doesn't actually validate that the fields in the `associatedModels` parameter belong to the model that was passed alongside it, likely because of the any keyword. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Use another generic parameter:

```
type SmartSearchParams<SpecificModel extends StandardModel, AssociatedModels extends StandardModel[]> = {
  search: string;
  model: SpecificModel;
  fields: ModelAttributes<SpecificModel>[];
  associatedModels: (AssociatedModels[number])[];
};

function coolestFunctionEver<
  SpecificModel extends StandardModel,
  AssociatedModels extends StandardModel[],
>(
  smartSearchParams: SmartSearchParams<SpecificModel, AssociatedModels>,
  associateModels: AssociatedModels,
) {
  ...
}
```

We use `(AssociatedModels[number])[]` because if a tuple is passed (`[Foo, Bar]`) for example it would require you to use `[Foo, Bar]` when passing the models. However if we use `[number]` and wrap it back into an array, we get `(Foo | Bar)[] which is more desirable.

Comment: The problem here is that it only accepts one type of model in the array for `associatedModels`. If my first associated model is `Receipt` for instance then the next model in the array is also required to be `Receipt` and I can't, for instance also include the `Address` model

Comment: I edited my answer to use a tuple/array for associatedModels instead; I must've missed that it was an array somehow!

Comment: This is exactly the piece of knowledge that I was missing. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nevermind, after some more testing, this doesn't solve the issue. Still, thanks for trying